# Regex and the colon (:)

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code. The idea is to detect whole words.

```
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch("Hello1 Hello2", @"\bHello\b"); // yields false
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch("Hello Hello2", @"\bHello\b"); // yields true
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch("Hello: Hello2", @"\bHello\b"); **// yields true, but should yield false**
```

Seems that Regex is ignoring the colon. How can I modify the code such that the last line will return false?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the colon? `Hello\:`

Comment: @Evan: `:` is not a meta-character for regexen.

Comment: There is no need to escape ':'

Comment: @sepp2k: Yes it is - a non-capturing group.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski Except he has not used a colon as part of his Regex pattern.

Comment: @Evan: only if preceded by `(?`, and only in the pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\b` means "word boundary". `:` is not part of any word, so the expression is true.

Maybe you want an expression like this:

```
(^|\s)Hello(\s|$)
```

Which means: *the string "Hello", preceded by either the start of the expression or a whitespace, and followed by either the end of the expression or a whitespace.*

Comment: This works, but also eats any whitespace before or after the word. For example, `echo "Hello qqq Hello qHelloq q Hello" | sed -E 's/(^|\s)Hello(\s|$)/#####/g'` gives `#####qqq#####qHelloq q#####`

Answer (score 3):

The Regex isn't ignoring the colon. The position before the colon is where `\b` matches, because `\b` matches word-boundaries. That means the position between a word-character and a non-word-chracter.

If you want Whitespace to follow after your word 'Hello', than use `"\bHello\s"`.

Answer (score 0):

To match a whole word not directly followed with a colon, use

```cs
\bHello\b(?!:)
\bHello(?![:\w])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rSJ7Rt/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Hello` - a word
- `(?![:\w])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `:` or a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

Se the [C# code demo](https://ideone.com/tBcKPt):

```cs
bool contains = Regex.IsMatch("Hello: Hello2", @"\bHello\b");
Console.WriteLine(contains); // => False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("Hello: Hello2", @"\bHello(?![:\w])"));
// => False
```